# Redirecting a product from category page to a landing page without redirecting the product page

Tags: category-products, landing-pages

Instead to the product page, I would like to direct our customers to a custom URL that holds our landing page from the category product... without affecting the product url.

Recommendation of an extension can also be an option.

Comment: Do you want to keep the sub url `http://yourshop.com/categoryname/product.html` intact, or only the direct product url `http://yourshop.com/product.html` ?

Comment: Would you like to redirect to a different URL or show your landing page in the same URL?

Comment: Milan: I would like to keep both of them intact.
Yiorgos: I would like to change the URL to another URL from the category page. I guess you can call it an override. But not looking for any kind of redirect using the original URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the product view page for the particular product.

First of all, create a Static Block with your landing page stuff in it. Let's call it "**product_xyz_landing**"

In your backend go to **Catalog -> Manage Product**s

Find you product and click **Edit**

Choose the Tab "**Design**" in the left"

Now in **Custom Layout Update**

Insert the following code

```
<reference name="content">
   <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info</name></action>
   <block type="cms/block" name="landing">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>product_xyz_landing</block_id><action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

I hope this helps.